# I am facing issues with the instagram API

Tags: api, graph, instagram

I am facing an issue with the Instagram API with the following error: "The media builder with creation id = 1823XXXXXX does not exist or has been expired.". It was working fine with a page access token method till yesterday. Suddenly from today, it's showing this error. When I searched many StackOverflow results mentioned that issue can be settled with a User access token and Page access token combination.

My query is that, whether it is able to access the user access token using existing page access token I have?

Answer (score -2):

Going through the error codes for graph API i could fine this:

- Error code: 24
- Sub Error Code: 2207008
- Err Message: The media builder with creation id = {creation-id} does not exist or has been expired.
- Resolution: Temporary error publishing a container. Try again 1–2 times in the next 30 seconds to 2 minutes. If unsuccessful, generate a new container ID and use it to try again.

Let me know if this helps! :D